# SQL between dates

Tags: php, sql, date, between

I have table with two columns (startdate & enddate) and I have two submission dates (2012-02-29 & 2012-03-30) I am trying to get the data between startdate (2012-02-29) and the enddate (2012-03-30)

I've tried

```
 i.startdate between '2012-02-29' and i.enddate '2012-03-30'
```

but that didnt work, I've been googling this for hours with no clear answer, any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly:

1. Your table contains two date fields, `StartDate` and `EndDate`, that describe a lengthy event.
2. You want to find all the events that fall completely within the period described by two other dates, in this case `2012-02-29` and `2012-03-30`.

If this is correct then use this:

```
 SELECT * FROM Events 
   WHERE StartDate >= '2012-02-29' AND EndDate <= '2012-03-30';
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM table_with_dates WHERE (i.startdate  BETWEEN '2012-02-29' AND '2012-03-30') AND (i.enddate  BETWEEN '2012-02-29' AND '2012-03-30')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
where ('2012-02-29' between i.startdate and i.enddate) and ('2012-03-30' between i.startdate and i.enddate)
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want both your submissions (two dates) between startdate and enddate?
so

```
Where (@firstDate between StartDate and EndDate) and (@secondDate between StartDate and EndDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the startdate and enddate are separate fields and you are looking for specific startdates and enddates you don't really need a between, just a

```
select ..... from ..... where i.startdate >= '2012-02-29' and i.enddate =< '2012-03-30'
```