# Filtering and displaying data in gridview from database based on date constraint

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datetime

Here is my tables:

```
create table users
(
userid int identity(1,1) primary key,
username varchar(150),
password varchar(20),
email varchar(150),
mobile varchar(50),
address varchar(2000),
service_start_date datetime,
createdate datetime,
modifydate datetime,
deletedate datetime,
tablestatus varchar(50),
roles varchar(50)


)



create table service_transaction
(
srvid int identity(1,1),
srv_startdate datetime,
srv_enddate datetime,
script varchar(1000),
position_type varchar(100),
entryprice varchar(100),
targetprice varchar(100),
comments varchar(100),
srv_type varchar(100),
srv_status varchar(100),
createdate datetime,
modifydate datetime,
deletedate datetime,
tablestatus varchar(50)

)



create table usersubscription
(
sub_id int identity(1,1) primary key,
u_id int foreign key references users(userid), 
sub_startdate datetime,
sub_enddate datetime,
service_type varchar(100),
createdate datetime,

modifydate datetime,
deletedate datetime,
tablestatus varchar(50)
)
```

I need a query to filter the service transactions for the particular user based on his subscription start date and subscription end date. Please help me.

Comment: is there any relation between table user and service transactions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL between dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9950340/sql-between-dates)

Comment: user is related with subscription if he is subscribed then he can view the transactions which lies between subscription start date and subscription end date.

Comment: is there any relation of `service_transaction` with `user` or `usersubscription`?

Comment: yes need to display transactions between sub_startdate and sub_enddate  but no releationship with user

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to normalise your tables a bit. Try the following, this from my understanding of your question.

```
DECLARE @filterDate AS DATETIME
SET @filterDate = '2014-05-05 17:04:45'
SELECT * FROM service_transaction AS ST
JOIN usersubscription AS US ON ST.srv_type = US.service_type
JOIN users AS U ON U.userid  = US.userid
WHERE @filterDate BETWEEN US.sub_startdate AND US.sub_enddate AND U.userid = '12345'
```

I've added a userId filter, you can replace 12345 with a userId that you're querying for.

Comment: thanks for answer but this query is giving me the all the transactions for all users but i need all transactions of particular user..

Comment: but in my application when user login only his particular transactions should display .. so plzz suggest me how to automate this query instead of giving manually..

Comment: Use a stored procedure, and pass the userid and date as parameters